# How can I restrict changing the max nested comment levels option to super admins?

Tags: multisite, comments, capabilities

I have an older theme that I've modified to support threaded comments.  I would like the individual admins in my multisite install to be able to choose whether threaded comments are enabled.  However, I'd like to restrict the ability to choose the maximum number of levels to super admins.

Looking at the capabilities, it seems that all capabilities for the settings screen are [grouped together as one capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_options).  Is it possible to restrict just this single option so that it is forced to be the same static value across the entire blog network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one hook for threaded comments depth - `thread_comments_depth_max` and it sets max value for depth ( default is 10 ), you can use this filter and set max depth fox non-Super Admins number that you want.

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_network' ) ) {
   mamaduka_thread_comments_depth_max( $maxdeep ){
       return 5; // or any number you want
   }
   add_filter( 'thread_comments_depth_max', 'mamaduka_thread_comments_depth_max' );
```